# Load more than one row from Active Directory with C# SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, active-directory

I'm having a heck of a time loading information from my active directory into my SSIS script.  I have the load part down (I have several sections to my project that are working properly, just not this one).  The problem I'm having is loading from Active Directory.

I have tried several different examples I have found online.  While I am familiar with programming, C# isn't my language of choice so its a little difficult to figure out what's wrong.

What I want to do is use a script component to get all of the users in our single-domain Active Directory.  The scripts I have tried sometimes return nothing, but often only return a single row.

The following is the code that I am currently using.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I am using the latest version of Visual Studio Community 2015 to build the SSIS stuff with C# 2015 to build the Script Component.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{

   try
   {

    string groupName = "Domain Users";
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mic.local");

    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
    //GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);


    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);


    foreach(UserPrincipal found in srch.FindAll())
    {

    //foreach (Principal found in grp.GetMembers(false))
    //{ 

        //UserPrincipal userFound = found as UserPrincipal;

        MyOutputBuffer.AddRow();
        MyOutputBuffer.LoginName = found.SamAccountName;
        MyOutputBuffer.OfficeLocation = found.GetOfficeLocation();
        MyOutputBuffer.Lastname = found.getLastName();
        MyOutputBuffer.Middlename = found.getMiddleName();
        MyOutputBuffer.Firstname = found.getFirstName();
        MyOutputBuffer.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(found.GetCreateDate());
        MyOutputBuffer.EmailAddress = found.getEmail();
        MyOutputBuffer.IsDeleted = Convert.ToBoolean(found.GetIsDeleted());

    }

    ctx.Dispose();
}
catch
{
   //
}
```

Comment: This code works for me.  Perhaps there are exceptions being thrown.  Could you log errors from the catch block or add a messagebox?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can show console output or even a message box because it's inside an SSIS component.  I can dump stuff out to a text file though.  I will give that a try and paste in in here shortly...

Comment: Ok, well, I thought I could.  Turns out the script component doesn't have an error output. :-(

Comment: You can another output buffer nad populate it in the catch block.  or add a breakpoint in the code and step through until you hit an error  or add to the catch block catch(exception e){Messagebox.show(e.Message);}

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll give that a try next. ;-)

Comment: Mark, you're a saint.  I had no idea how to step into the debugger prior to this.  Thank you so much for that!

Comment: Thank you Mark, that helped a lot.  I was able to get past that error because I was able to use the debugger.